# "Do you have <past participle>?" or "Have you <past participle>?"

Tags: questions, present-perfect

Which one of the following sentences is grammatically correct?

> Why do you have added this tag?
>
> Why have you added this tag?

In my opinion the second one is correct and I use it for my writings, but today I have seen the first form and I am in doubt if the first one is correct or not?

Comment: Can you add some context about where you encountered the first form?

Comment: @snailboat Hi thanks for your replay, I've found it in a forum somewhere in the Internet among a bunch of conversations between people. Unfortunately I can't provide more context about it, but which would you use as a native English speaker ? (in daily speaking)

Comment: @snailboat You're absolutely right! real sentences were `Why do you have added Android tag to this article?` and `Why have you added Android tag to this article?`

Comment: @snailboat Thanks! Could you please tell me which is more usual in US?

Comment: The first is ungrammatical, so that sort of makes the second more usual by default :-)  Personally, I would probably say "Why did you add this tag?" instead, though.

Comment: @snailboat I sincerely grateful for your answer. If you would like write this as an answer so that it might be helpful for other readers.

Comment: And speakers of British English would prefer *Why have you added this tag?* @snailboat This difference is one thing I've learned here. This is just a general comment, not necessarily germane to this question.

Comment: With no evidence to show that OP *regularly* encounters the first form, and no argument to show *why* he might find it "plausible", I think this question is Off Topic. We cannot be expected to endorse asking questions here for every one-off error made by a non-native speaker, *unless* that non-native speaker is an ELL user who can explain why he's confused about correct usage. Vague references to "someone used it on a forum" don't justify asking about totally invalid constructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is not grammatically correct. Second sentence is correct according to grammar and is also the way it is used in standard English. But in spoken English this is used as well:

> Why did you add this tag?

Past participle is usually used when the effect of an action is still present, whereas past simple is not concerned with any of that